How to Resolve TypeScript Error for Dynamic product Object in Vue 3 Template
I am working on a Vue 3 component with TypeScript, and I'm encountering a TypeScript error related to the product object in the template. The error occurs specifically in these lines:
@close="closePopup(product)"
@click.passive="changePrice(product)"

The error message is:

Argument of type '{ text: string; price: number; label: ProductLabelT;
multiplier?: number; type: "INITIAL_COST_PRODUCT" |
"MONTHLY_COST_PRODUCT" | "YEARLY_COST_PRODUCT" |
"MEMBERSHIP_FEE_PRODUCT" | ... 5 more ... | "KAUTION_PRODUCT"; ... 10
more ...; badgeDescription: string; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to
parameter of type 'ProductTypeT'.ts(2345)

Here is a simplified version of my component code:
<template>
  <div class="flex gap-4 sm:flex-row flex-col w-full">
    <div class="flex w-full flex-col items-center">
      <h1 class="text-xl font-semibold text-green-700">Preise</h1>
      <loaderVue v-if="loading" />
      <div v-else class="w-full">
        <div :key="product.type" v-for="product in consumer_products" @click.passive="changePrice(product)" :class="product.bgColor" v-if="product.show" class="flex active:bg-gray-100 group relative hover:bg-gray-50 transition cursor-pointer p-4 flex-col border-b w-full items-center">
          <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
            <changePriceNew :is-admin="isAdmin" :label="product.label" :multiplier="product.multiplier" @done="updatePrices" :product-label="product.productLabelName" @close="closePopup(product)" :helptext="product.helptext" v-if="product.open" :group="group" :product-type="product.type" :tax-multiplier="product.taxMultiplier" :price="returnCurrentPrice(product.price, product.history)" :product-can-be-deactivated="product.productCanBeDeactivated" :product-deactivated="product.productDeactivated" />
          </transition>
          <h3 class="text-gray-600 mb-4 font-semibold">
            {{ product.text }}
          </h3>
          <!-- Other template code -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { computed, ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import { GetGroupPricesQuery, Group, ProductTypes, Priceentry } from "~/src/API";
import tooltipVue from "../popup/tooltip.vue";
import changePriceNew from "../popup/changePriceNew.vue";
import loaderVue from "../loader/loader.vue";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import { Organizationtypes } from "~/src/models";
import paths from "@/static/languages/path.json";
import { ProductLabelT, ProductNameLableT } from "types";
import newPrice from "../popup/newPrice.vue";
import { useStore } from "~/composables";
import badge from "@/components/item/badge.vue";

type ProductTypeTBase = {
  text: string;
  price: number | Ref<number>;
  label: ProductLabelT;
  multiplier?: number;
  type: keyof typeof ProductTypes;
  history: Priceentry[] | Ref<Priceentry[]>;
  open: boolean;
  bgColor?: string;
  show: boolean;
  taxMultiplier: number;
  productLabelName: ProductNameLableT;
  helptext?: { what?: string; why?: string; how?: string };
  showTax?: boolean | ComputedRef<boolean>;
};

type ProductTypeTConditional =
  | (ProductTypeTBase & {
      productCanBeDeactivated: true;
      productDeactivated: ComputedRef<boolean>;
      badgeDescription: string;
    })
  | (ProductTypeTBase & {
      productCanBeDeactivated: false;
      productDeactivated?: never;
      badgeDescription?: never;
    });

export type ProductTypeT = ProductTypeTConditional;

export default {
  props: {
    group: {
      type: Object as () => Group,
      default: () => ({} as Group),
    },
  },
  components: {
    tooltipVue,
    changePriceNew,
    loaderVue,
    newPrice,
    badge,
  },
  setup(props) {
    const loading = ref(true);
  let consumer_products = ref<ProductTypeT[]>([
      {
        text: 'Einspeisung Preis pro kWh',
        price: producer_price,
        label: 'Cent/kWh',
        productLabelName: 'ct/kWh',
        type: 'PRODUCER_PRODUCT',
        multiplier: 100,
        open: false,
        history: production_cost_history,
        show: true,
        taxMultiplier: 1.2,
        helptext: {
          what: paths.helptext.production_product.what,
          why: paths.helptext.production_product.why,
          how: paths.helptext.production_product.how,
        },
        showTax: true,
        productCanBeDeactivated: false,
      },
      {
        text: 'Bezug Preis pro kWh',
        price: consumption_price,
        label: 'Cent/kWh',
        productLabelName: 'ct/kWh',
        type: 'CONSUMER_PRODUCT',
        multiplier: 100,
        open: false,
        history: consumption_cost_history,
        show: true,
        taxMultiplier: 1.2,
        helptext: {
          what: paths.helptext.consumption_product.what,
          why: paths.helptext.consumption_product.why,
          how: paths.helptext.consumption_product.how,
        },
        showTax: showTaxIfAdminOrNoUST,
        productCanBeDeactivated: false,
      },
      {
        text: 'Genossenschaftsbeitrag Einmalig',
        label: 'EUR',
        productLabelName: 'EUR/Einmalig',
        price: cooperative_fee_cost,
        type: 'COOPERATIVE_FEE_PRODUCT',
        open: false,
        history: cooperative_cost_history,
        show: props.group.organization_type === Organizationtypes.COOPERATIVE,
        taxMultiplier: 1,
        helptext: {
          what: ' Für Genossenschaftsmitglieder wird bei der Anmeldung ein Genossenschaftsbeitrag verlangt.',
          why: 'Der jährliche Mitgliedsbeitrag ermöglicht es jährliche Mitgliedsbeiträge einzuheben.',
          how: `
          Es werden hier keine Umsatzsteuer angewandt.

          \n
               Der Mitgliedsbeitrag wird einmalig pro Mitglied angewandt, sobald ein neuer Benutzer die Gemeinschaft beitritt.


          `,
        },
        showTax: showTaxIfAdminOrNoUST,
        productCanBeDeactivated: false,
      },
      {
        text: 'Mitgliedsbeitrag Jährlich',
        label: 'EUR/Jahr',
        productLabelName: 'EUR/Jahr',
        price: membership_fee_cost,
        type: 'MEMBERSHIP_FEE_PRODUCT',
        open: false,
        history: membership_cost_history,
        taxMultiplier: 1.2,
        helptext: {
          what: paths.helptext.yearly_membership.what,
          why: paths.helptext.yearly_membership.why,
          how: paths.helptext.yearly_membership.how,
        },
        showTax: showTaxIfAdminOrNoUST,
        show: props.group.organization_type === Organizationtypes.ASSOCIATION,
        productCanBeDeactivated: true,
        productDeactivated: computed(
          () => props.group.membership_fee_deactivated
        ),
        badgeDescription: paths.products.badge.membership_fee,
      },
      {
        text: 'Einmalige Kosten',
        price: initial_cost,
        label: 'EUR',
        productLabelName: 'EUR/Einmalig',
        type: 'INITIAL_COST_PRODUCT',
        open: false,
        history: initial_cost_history,
        show: true,
        taxMultiplier: 1.2,
        helptext: {
          what: paths.helptext.initial_product.what,
          why: paths.helptext.initial_product.why,
          how: paths.helptext.initial_product.how,
        },
        showTax: showTaxIfAdminOrNoUST,
        productCanBeDeactivated: true,
        productDeactivated: computed(
          () => props.group.initial_cost_deactivated
        ),
        badgeDescription: paths.products.badge.initial_cost,
      },
      {
        text: 'Kaution',
        price: kaution_cost,
        label: 'EUR',
        productLabelName: 'EUR/Einmalig',
        type: 'KAUTION_PRODUCT',
        open: false,
        history: kaution_cost_history,
        show: true,
        taxMultiplier: 1,
        helptext: {
          what: paths.helptext.initial_product.what,
          why: paths.helptext.initial_product.why,
          how: paths.helptext.initial_product.how,
        },
        showTax: showTaxIfAdminOrNoUST,
        productCanBeDeactivated: false,
      },
      {
        text: 'Grundpreis Monatlich',
        label: 'EUR/Monat',
        productLabelName: 'EUR/Monat',
        price: monthly_cost,
        type: 'MONTHLY_COST_PRODUCT',
        open: false,
        history: monthly_cost_history,
        show: true,
        taxMultiplier: 1.2,
        helptext: {
          what: paths.helptext.monthly_product.what,
          why: paths.helptext.monthly_product.why,
          how: paths.helptext.monthly_product.how,
        },
        showTax: showTaxIfAdminOrNoUST,
        productCanBeDeactivated: true,
        productDeactivated: computed(
          () => props.group.monthly_cost_deactivated
        ),
        badgeDescription: paths.products.badge.monthly_cost,
      },
      {
        text: 'Grundpreis Jährlich',
        label: 'EUR/Jahr',
        productLabelName: 'EUR/Jahr',
        price: yearly_cost,
        type: 'YEARLY_COST_PRODUCT',
        open: false,
        history: yearly_cost_history,
        show: true,
        taxMultiplier: 1.2,
        helptext: {
          what: paths.helptext.yearly_product.what,
          why: paths.helptext.yearly_product.why,
          how: paths.helptext.yearly_product.how,
        },
        showTax: showTaxIfAdminOrNoUST,
        productCanBeDeactivated: true,
        productDeactivated: computed(() => props.group.yearly_cost_deactivated),
        badgeDescription: paths.products.badge.yearly_cost,
      },
    ])

    onMounted(async () => {
      const prices = await apiQuery("getGroupPrices", {
        groupId: props.group.id,
      });
      loading.value = false;
      updatePrices(prices.data.getGroupPrices);
    });

    function updatePrices(data: GetGroupPricesQuery["getGroupPrices"]) {
      // Update logic here
    }

    const isAdmin = computed(() => useStore().getters.isAdmin);

    function changePrice(product: ProductTypeT) {
      closeAllProducts();
      product.open = true;
    }

    function closePopup(product: ProductTypeT) {
      product.open = false;
    }

    function closeAllProducts() {
      consumer_products.value.forEach((p) => (p.open = false));
    }

    return {
      loading,
      consumer_products,
      isAdmin,
      changePrice,
      closePopup,
      updatePrices,
    };
  },
};
</script>


My question is: How can I fix the TypeScript error related to the product object in the template to ensure that product is correctly inferred as ProductTypeT?

At least this productDeactivated: ComputedRef<boolean> will make the type incompatible. It's unclear why refs are in the type. Generally you'll need to to normalize an object to avoid the problems with ref unwrapping. Otherwise this will happen any way when it becomes a part of another reactive object, like this happens with consumer_products

@EstusFlask the reason because i used ComputedRef<boolean> is that the state is not reactive. when props.group.membership_fee changes it does not reflect in the UI, the solution was to use computed property for it

It's not shown where product objects come from. I mean there will be no refs and computeds due to ref unwrapping when product obj becomes reactive. If it's supposed to be reactive, wrap it with reactive() asap, and the type should reflect this. In other places you used number | Ref . There's https://vuejs.org/api/utility-types#mayberef for this case

@EstusFlask i have updated the products array of objects

This will result in productDeactivated: boolean type in consumer_products. Try if this will fix type error
